# custom structure of zipfile of python

Tags: python, zip

I'd like to create a new zip file using python. 
I'd like to zip files from different directories and put it in one zip file with custom folder structure.

My source will come from

```
/mydir/sample1.txt
/mydir/data/sample1_data.txt
```

The desired zip structure looks like this

```
sample1.txt
/Data/sample1_data.txt
```

Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: All information you need could be found in the documentation of the standard `zipfile` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sciroccorics suggested everything is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).

A short example would be something like:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('out.zip', 'w') as z:
    z.write('/mydir/sample1.txt', 'sample1.txt')
    z.write('/mydir/data/sample1_data.txt', '/Data/sample1_data.txt')
```

Answer (score -1):

Python has a built in zip library

```
mydir = 'mydir'
myzipfile = 'fancy.zip'
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
with ZipFile(myzipfile, 'w') as zipout:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mydir):
        for filename in filenames:
            with open(os.path.join(dirpath[len(mydir)+1:], filename), 'r') as fin:
                with zipout.open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), 'w') as fout:
                    fout.write(fin.read())
```

This will take all the files from mydir and copy them into fancy.zip
It will also recurse into subdirectories of mydir and copy those files as well.

Comment: I think the question was how to write a file to zip using a *different* structure than the operating system file structure

Comment: This does use a slightly different structure, the dirpath[len(mydir)+1:] bit chops off the root directory